# What should I do when I cannot connect to the keyserver?

Tags: gpg

Due to *some reason*, I cannot access *any* keyserver in Mainland China.

Which means I have to manually search (with proxy enabled) for keys and manually trust them.

Is there a better way for that?

I did try to configure Thunderbird and KDE to connect via proxy but they don't seem to work...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "cannot access"? Are you receiving timeouts?

Comment: @Panki Put simply, I'm behind a firewall, even `ping keyserver.ubuntu.com` would yield all packets lost. But I can't get proxy settings of thunderbird to work so I am asking for an alternative.